# select query of any table using spark.sql giving zero records sometimes but same select query giving result in HIVE CLI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

```
Val result=spark.sql("select * from employee")
```

is giving zero results sometimes even though the data present in the hive.

while executing the same select query in HIVE CLI result's we are getting

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try doing below before running your query, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html)

```
hive> Msck repair table <db_name>.<table_name>
```